# Evenly space href img's in div

Tags: css, html, alignment, image

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to evenly space 3 href img's on both sides in a div container.

visual example: [  X  X  X  ]

(X = href img [ ]=container div)

```
<div id="container">
  <a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="image3.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  clear: both;
  width: 900px;
  height: 150px;
}
#container a img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How wide are your images?, do you want them centralised and evenly spaced?

Answer (score 0):

ok since you want them evenly spaced, I suggest using percentages as the width for your images. for example:

```
#container {
  clear: both;
  width: 900px;
  height: 150px;
}
#container a img {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

this should float your anchors within the parent div so they will align horizontally

Comment: or place the images in their own divs within the container depending on the size of the aforementioned images

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YRQze/2/). Tested in Chrome 21, IE9, FF13, Safari 5, Opera 11.

```
#container {
  clear: both;
  width: 900px;
  height: 150px;
}
#container a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
#container a img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#container a {float:left; padding:0 10px}
```